# How to append the new content in angulularJS template in ng -repeat without destroying previous content

Tags: angularjs

How to append the new content in angulularJS template in ng -repeat without destroying previous content
1.I want to dispaly the myvar data in every save click

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,        $http, $filter, $rootScope) {

        $scope.view= function () {
             //some ajax calll

                  $scope.myvar = data;
        };
    }]);

</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<ul>
    <li class="Status" ng-repeat="item in myvar">
        {{item.var}}
    </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="view()">View More</button>
```

2.I please suggest me

Comment: so what is the issue? its not happening or what?

Comment: I mean if i click _view more_ button the new content will display. That's fine, but i i click again that button new content replaces existing i.e. previous content so i want just append `<li>` not replace thank you

Comment: So instead push the new values

Answer (score 0):

According to [ng-repead documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) (check Tracking and Duplicates section) "track by $index" is what you need

```
<li class="Status" ng-repeat="item in myvar track by $index">
  {{item.var}}
</li>
```

You can also use "track by yuor_primary_key".

Answer (score 0):

You need to push new element every time in array
Check this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEwBwQ

### Controller

```
angular.module('DemoApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
  .controller('DemoController', function($scope, $window, $state) {
    $scope.myvar = [{"var" : 1}];
    $scope.save = function() {
      //some ajax calll
      var v = {"var" : 1};
      $scope.myvar.push(v);
    };

  });
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="Status" ng-repeat="item in myvar">
    {{item.var}}
  </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="save()">save</button>
```